# PostgreSQL Index Use On Joins

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

There are numerous posts on the use of indexes, and I'm trying to understand, but I'm hopeful someone can help with my specific issue.  I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE f4111
(
  costcenter_ilmcu character varying(12), -- Business Unit
  documenttype_ildct character varying(2), -- Document Type
  ordertype_ildcto character varying(2), -- Order Type
  documentorderinvoicee_ildoco numeric, -- Document (Order No Invoice etc.)
  datetransactionjulian_iltrdj date, -- Date - Order/Transaction
  uniquekeyidinternal_ilukid numeric NOT NULL, -- Unique Key ID (Internal)
  CONSTRAINT f4111_pk PRIMARY KEY (uniquekeyidinternal_ilukid)
);
```

This tables has hundreds of millions of records, so the actual content is split by annual partitions:

```
create table f4111_2011 (
  constraint f4111_2011_ck1 check
      (datetransactionjulian_iltrdj between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31')
) inherits (f4111);
```

There is one of these per year, going back quite a bit.  Each of the partitions has the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX f4111_2011_idx5 ON f4111_2011 (documenttype_ildct, ordertype_ildcto);
CREATE INDEX f4111_2011_idx6 ON f4111_2011 (documentorderinvoicee_ildoco);
```

My goal is to pull the minimum transaction date for each of the 15,000 or so work orders in this table:

```
create table open_work_orders (
  wo numeric not null
)
```

This works:

```
insert into earliest_transaction_dates
SELECT 
  v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco, min (v.datetransactionjulian_iltrdj)
FROM 
  f4111 v
  join work_orders w on
    v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco = w.wo
WHERE
  v.documenttype_ildct = 'IM' and
  v.costcenter_ilmcu = '1AM' and
  v.ordertype_ildcto = 'WO' and
  v.datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01' -- to invoke check constraint
group by
  v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco;
```

But it takes over 9 minutes to produce the 15,000 desired results.  It does not appear to make use of the index `f4111_2011_idx6`.

This goes against everything I hold dear, but when I do it like this:

```
for work_order in select work_order_id from work_orders
loop
  insert into earliest_transaction_dates
  SELECT 
    work_order, min (v.datetransactionjulian_iltrdj)
  FROM 
    f4111 v
  WHERE
    v.documenttype_ildct = 'IM' and
    v.costcenter_ilmcu = '1AM' and
    v.ordertype_ildcto = 'WO' and
    v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco = work_order and
    v.datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01';
 end loop;
```

it **does** make use of the index and finishes in 2:14.

I realize I'm missing something fundamental here, but is there a way to make the 9 minute version of the query use the index on `documentorderinvoicee_ildoco`?

I am on 9.5.0 (fantastic, by the way), and all of my stats are up to date.

--- Edit ---

Per request, I am adding the following additional info.

- Version: 9.5.0
- Cardinality:

  - open_work_orders : 15,422 records
  - f4111 : approx 78,000,000 records
  - f4111 partitions : average 8,000,000 records per

The queries I listed are abbreviated, for the sake of demonstrating the issue at hand.  Each table actually has quite a few more fields and more indexes.  I listed only the fields/indexes sufficient to demonstrate the issue.

Explain plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=2071976.16..2101248.07 rows=21992 width=13)
  Group Key: v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=2071976.16..2096083.48 rows=988933 width=13)
        Merge Cond: (((w.wo)::numeric) = v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco)
        ->  Sort  (cost=1584.03..1622.58 rows=15422 width=4)
              Sort Key: ((w.wo)::numeric)
              ->  Seq Scan on open_work_order_1am w  (cost=0.00..511.22 rows=15422 width=4)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=2070392.13..2077443.30 rows=1410233 width=13)
              ->  Sort  (cost=2070392.13..2073917.71 rows=1410233 width=13)
                    Sort Key: v.documentorderinvoicee_ildoco
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1902253.44 rows=1410233 width=13)
                          ->  Seq Scan on f4111_view v  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                          ->  Index Scan using f4111_9999_idx5 on f4111_9999 v_1  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=40)
                                Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                          ->  Index Scan using f4111_2017_idx5 on f4111_2017 v_2  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=40)
                                Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f4111_2016 v_3  (cost=511.81..13612.41 rows=9453 width=12)
                                Recheck Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f4111_2016_idx5  (cost=0.00..509.44 rows=20502 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f4111_2015 v_4  (cost=13279.30..378625.74 rows=277646 width=13)
                                Recheck Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f4111_2015_idx5  (cost=0.00..13209.89 rows=576546 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f4111_2014 v_5  (cost=14262.66..400904.20 rows=286705 width=13)
                                Recheck Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f4111_2014_idx5  (cost=0.00..14190.98 rows=619055 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f4111_2013 v_6  (cost=13026.39..430799.00 rows=233531 width=13)
                                Recheck Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f4111_2013_idx5  (cost=0.00..12968.00 rows=567557 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f4111_2012 v_7  (cost=12008.94..348884.89 rows=256980 width=13)
                                Recheck Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f4111_2012_idx5  (cost=0.00..11944.69 rows=520026 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f4111_2011 v_8  (cost=15274.23..329410.87 rows=345915 width=13)
                                Recheck Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
                                Filter: ((datetransactionjulian_iltrdj >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((costcenter_ilmcu)::text = '1AM'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f4111_2011_idx5  (cost=0.00..15187.75 rows=660732 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (((documenttype_ildct)::text = 'IM'::text) AND ((ordertype_ildcto)::text = 'WO'::text))
```

Comment: Edit your question, and paste this [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: I believe I've added the information you requested.  If I missed something, let me know.  The OS didn't seem relevant, but it's RedHat in case you needed to know.

Comment: CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. Make it easy to participate. As it is, anyone who might want to help must reverse-engineer the tables earliest_transaction_dates and work_orders from your select statements. Your loop eliminates a join and a `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I understand your point.  I'll find a way to mock up some data that illustrates the core issue.